# Why I am getting the following AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am using the sklearn's GradientBoostingRegression method. So after fitting it with 2000 estimators, I wanted to add more estimators to it. Since it is taking too long to rerun the entire fitting process, I used the set_params() method. Note that it is a multi-target problem, meaning, I have 3 targets to fit. So I am using the following code to add more estimators.

```
'''parameters: models (list  of length 3 in our case )
               train_X, train_y [n_samples x 3], test
               n_estimators : previous + 500 (default) [additional estimators]
               warm_start : True (default)
'''

def addMoreEstimators(train_X, train_y, test, models, n_estimators = 500, warm_start=True):
    params = {'n_estimators':n_estimators, 'warm_start':warm_start}

    gbm_pred= pd.DataFrame()

    for (i,stars),clf in zip(enumerate(['*','**','***']), models):
        clf.set_params(**params)
        %time clf.fit(train_X.todense(),train_y[stars])
        %time gbm_pred[stars] = clf.predict(test.todense())

    gbm_pred = gbm_pred.as_matrix()    
    gbm_dict ={'model': gbm, 'prediction': gbm_pred}

    return gbm_dict
```

Note: the `models` parameter is a list of 3 fitted models for the 3 targets.

When I ran it for the first time using 2500 (originally I had 2000 estimators), it ran fine and gave me an output.

When, I am running the same function using 3000 estimators, I am getting an `AttributeError` (see the traceback of the error below). Here the models contained the 3 fitted models. Below is the traceback of the error: (it's kinda long)

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-9418ada3b36f> in <module>()
      7                                                                 test = val_X_tfidf[:,shortened_col_index],
      8                                                                 models = models,
----> 9                                                                 n_estimators = 3000)
     10 
     11 reduced_features_gbm_pred_3000_2_lr_1_msp_2 = reduced_features_gbm_model_3000_2_lr_1_msp_2['prediction']

<ipython-input-103-e15a4fb70b50> in addMoreEstimators(train_X, train_y, test, models, n_estimators, warm_start)
     15         
     16         clf.set_params(**params)
---> 17         get_ipython().magic(u'time clf.fit(train_X.todense(),train_y[stars])')
     18         print 'starting prediction'
     19 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2305         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2306         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2307         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2308 
   2309     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2226                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2227             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2228                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2229             return result
   2230 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1160         if mode=='eval':
   1161             st = clock2()
-> 1162             out = eval(code, glob, local_ns)
   1163             end = clock2()
   1164         else:

<timed eval> in <module>()

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, monitor)
    973                                     self.estimators_.shape[0]))
    974             begin_at_stage = self.estimators_.shape[0]
--> 975             y_pred = self._decision_function(X)
    976             self._resize_state()
    977 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.pyc in _decision_function(self, X)
   1080         # not doing input validation.
   1081         score = self._init_decision_function(X)
-> 1082         predict_stages(self.estimators_, X, self.learning_rate, score)
   1083         return score
   1084 

sklearn/ensemble/_gradient_boosting.pyx in sklearn.ensemble._gradient_boosting.predict_stages (sklearn/ensemble/_gradient_boosting.c:2502)()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Sorry for the long traceback, but I think it wouldn't be possible to provide me with meaningful feedback.

Again, why am I getting this feedback ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**
Below is the code that generates the `models` that was one of the inputs in the above function.

```
from sklearn import ensemble
def updated_runGBM(train_X, train_y, test, 
           n_estimators =100, 
           max_depth = 1, 
           min_samples_split=1,
           learning_rate=0.01, 
           loss= 'ls',
           warm_start=True):
    '''train_X : n_samples x m_features
       train_y : n_samples x k_targets (multiple targets allowed)
       test    : n_samples x m_features
       warm_start : True (originally the default is False, but I want to add trees)
    '''
    params = {'n_estimators': n_estimators, 'max_depth': max_depth, 'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
              'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'loss': loss,'warm_start':warm_start}
    gbm1 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
    gbm2 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
    gbm3 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

    gbm = [gbm1,gbm2,gbm3]

    gbm_pred= pd.DataFrame()
    for (i,stars),clf in zip(enumerate(['*','**','***']), gbm):
        %time clf.fit(train_X.todense(),train_y[stars])
        %time gbm_pred[stars] = clf.predict(test.todense())

    gbm_pred = gbm_pred.as_matrix()
    gbm_pred = np.clip(gbm_pred,0,np.inf)       
    gbm_dict ={'model': gbm, 'prediction': gbm_pred}       

    return gbm_dict
```

**NOTE** In the code above, I have removed some of the print statements to reduce clutter.

These are the two functions I am using, nothing else (apart from the code to split up the data).

Comment: Looking at this line: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_gradient_boosting.c#L2494 it seems clf.estimators_ contains an int, where it should contain DecisionTreeRegressor instances. I can't see anywhere in GradientBoostingClassifier() where this would happen, but it's possibly there's a bug. Alternatively, are you doing anything that would overwrite an entry in the estimators_ array?

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoQueiro for your reply. No, I am not doing anything to overwrite either the estimators_array or any other internal stuff, unless it is happening without my knowledge.

Comment: It will be hard for anyone to help you with this if they can't reproduce the problem. You should either try to work out the simplest code+data combination that reproduces the problem, or start delving into sklearn's code to work out what is putting an int into estimators_. This could be a bug in sklearn...

Comment: you need to at least post the code that generates "models", but better yet post a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit my post soon and put in the code that generates the models. I will also try to see if I get the same error on a randomly generated set.